# Cannot use `pbpaste` in Emacs to paste Chinese characters

Tags: process, character-encoding, clipboard

I'm using macOS. I tried using the following command to paste from clipboard in Emacs(started with `emacs -Q`)

```
(call-process "/usr/bin/pbpaste" nil t nil)
```

It works fine for English characters, but not for Chinese characters. For example, if I copy the following Chinese characters in web browser

```
中文测试
```

Then run the `call-process` command above in Emacs, the result would be

```
????
```

My system encoding is UTF-8 and I checked Emacs' encoding system was UTF-8 too(By checking the value of `buffer-file-coding-system` in Emacs, which was `'utf-8`).

How to sovle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer, just add the following line to your Emacs config file:

```
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

The reason is that `pbpaste` uses the encoding set by the environment variable `LANG`, by default Emacs don't set this variable, so you need to set it manually. Check [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24639415/1031769) for more details.